# Adding/Viewing/Deleting Data from HBase using PHP and Mapreduce in Java?

Tags: java, php, mapreduce, hbase

Hi friends
i am generating a web crawler, i like to know some things about that,
1)Can i use Map reduce to Fetch the Data from the NET
2)Can i able to save the Fetched data to HBase?
3)Can i able to Write an App in PHP for Fetch the Data from HBase?if yes can u gave me a code snippet??How can i Adding/Viewing/Deleting Data from HBase using PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your questions, yes, it can all be done. How you approach it depends on what exactly you want to achieve.

1) Your main control would need to partition the task. You would likely maintain some kind of list of addresses to crawl, possible running sequential mapreduce tasks that each time read the list in, split the list between mappers which could do the crawling, and write directly to hbase or another intermediary. They would also probably output generated urls to crawl next which in turn would be filtered down to uniques in the reduce phase, with the reduce outputting the list of things to crawl next. You'd need to maintain a list of recently crawled stuff and filter that out too, but that's not specific to MR/Hbase.

2) You can use [table output format](http://hbase.apache.org/docs/r0.20.6/api/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/mapreduce/TableOutputFormat.html) to send the outputs to hbase. You can also just make HBase connections with HTable and write directly in your mapper.

3) As TheDeveloper said, yes, with thrift. His link is good.

Answer (score 1):

For questions number 3, you can interact with Hbase from PHP, but you need to do it via the Thrift interface. See [this blog post](http://www.appaquet.com/2008/11/thrift-hbase-php.html) for more info. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

Can be done easily via REST using Stargate.